# Update WP CLI Package

Tags: wordpress, composer-php, wp-cli

Seems easy enough, referencing [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/318167/xdg-open-is-not-recognized-by-wp-cli-admin-command/319302?noredirect=1#comment471780_319302) im trying to update the `admin-command` package.

What i've tried:
uninstalling the package altogether, and installing it fresh by:

`wp package uninstall wp-cli/admin-command`

installing the package:

`wp package install wp-cli/admin-command`

after this i ran `wp package list` to see which version was installed

wp-cli/admin-command -> dev-master

PS > wp admin --path="some/wp/install" still shows

'xdg-open' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

@schlessera advised me in [this comment](https://github.com/wp-cli/admin-command/issues/15#issuecomment-439079571) to install the tagged version 2.0.0, 'I just tagged the release. Make sure you get the v2.0.0 tagged release, not some previous version.'

How do i do that?

Comment: You could just [install it manually](https://github.com/wp-cli/admin-command/archive/v2.0.0.zip)

Comment: And might you also know how i can install it from the commandline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp package install "wp-cli/admin-command:^2"`
You can add version requirements after the packagename devided by a ':'